# Access backend PHP file with JS Next React App, what's the path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path

I have a website where logged in users have a session stored.
I want to access this session data, check if they are logged in, and then permit them to use a react app.

I'm trying this JS code on my `index.tsx`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch('./auth_endpoint.php')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      router.push(`/login?sp=${encodeURIComponent(router.asPath)}`);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
}, []);
```

But error in console returns:

`GET http://[server-ip]:[test-port]/auth_endpoint.php 404 (Not Found)`

both `index.tsx` and `auth_endpoint.php` are located at `/home/test/public_html/demo/`

I can't figure what is the right syntax for the path here to import the php file correctly. also, I don't think it should be using a GET in the first place, this needs to happen server side.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a user is logged in and permit them to use a React app, it's a good practice to handle authentication on the server side and not rely on a client-side script like your current code. You can use sessions and server-side logic to perform the authentication checks.

First, ensure that the PHP script auth_endpoint.php handles the session and authentication logic. It should return a response based on the user's authentication status. Here's an example of what auth_endpoint.php might look like:

```html
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // User is authenticated
    http_response_code(200); // OK status
} else {
    // User is not authenticated
    http_response_code(401); // Unauthorized status
}
?>
```

Now, In the script above, if the user is authenticated (that is,if they have a valid session), it returns status OK 200. If the user is not authenticated, it returns a 401 Unauthorised status.

Next,you'll need to update your React code to fetch the PHP script and act based on the response you get.

```html
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/demo/auth_endpoint.php', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include' // Send cookies with the request
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // User is authenticated, permit access
      } else if (response.status === 401) {
        // User is not authenticated, redirect to login
        router.push(`/login?sp=${encodeURIComponent(router.asPath)}`);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}, []);
```

Make sure to specify the correct path to auth_endpoint.php in the fetch call (e.g., /demo/auth_endpoint.php), and set credentials: 'include' to send cookies with the request, which is important for sessions.

Don't forget to validate user sessions and perform authentication on the server side to ensure security. The client-side code is just for making the appropriate redirects or UI changes based on the server's response.